# asp:GridView change header cell style

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I would like to change style of my header cell after clicking on it. I'm using `GridView` control in `.Net 2.0`. Oh! my grid is sortable so after clicking on header, postback is triggered

Answer (score 0):

youll have to do in JS or jQuery ( if you want to prevent postbacks).

for saving the states of the style between each postback - i will suggest to save style and column location - in a hidden field which will be read after each postback  - *at the client side* - and will - regenerate the style.

Comment: hidden field valu after postback will be canceled so whats the point of reading it?